# Make OpenStack store all instances on Cinder

Tags: storage, openstack

I have been messing around with openstack for a little time, setting up a test environment. One thing i never found out was how to store my instances on cinder...

Does anyone here know how i can store all my instances on cinder instead of the compute host...?